# How to escape the . when using dot notation commandline arguments

Tags: omegaconf

I want to pass in a config like:

```
foo
    blah.bar: blah.bar
    another.thing: some.thing
```

And I want to do this on the commmandline, osmething like:

```
python my_script.py foo.blah.bar=blah.bar foo.another.thing=some.thing
```

Obviously, this would give me instead:

```
foo
    blah
        bar: blah.bar
    another
        thing: some.thing
```

... which is not what I want. How can I escape any periods (`.`) when using dot notation with `omegaconf.OmegaConf.from_cli()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment [here](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/22#issuecomment-331881572), I think you could do something like:

```
python my_script.py foo[blah.bar]=blah.bar foo[another.thing]=some.thing
```

But I've never used omegaconf, so please don't beat me up for guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported.
You can file a feature request but it's not going to be high priority. I suggest that you use a different separator in your keys.

Comment: Works now.....?

Comment: It does not work now.